# MySQL query to check a row's cells for value and return column name

Tags: php, mysql

I have been struggling with a certain query all day and I decided to ask for help.

I need a query that checks an entire table row and all its table cells for a value 'yes' and then it needs to give me the names of the columns where this is true.

[image: example table]

To clarify with an example:
in the table above I need to check the fruit row for all the cells with the value 'yes' and have the corresponding column names returned to me. In this case the result would be 'banana', 'apple' and 'pear'.

I hope that example helps.

```
-- pseudo code
SELECT `COLUMN_NAMES`
FROM `My_Table`
ROW `fruit`
WHERE `value` = 'yes';
```

I'd also like to note that I can't rearrange my database. The db structure can't be changed because we are already doing queries like SELECT 'property' WHERE 'Banana' = 'yes'(which would return 'fruit'). I need it to work the other way around too.

Comment: what is the name of the column with values fruit and liquid? What is your expected output?

Comment: If you need to do a query like this, you have a poor table design. Data that you need to return from queries should be in cell contents, not table or column names.

Comment: This looks like a horrible DB structure. You should look into *database normalization*.

Comment: I guess you could call that 'property' or something like that. Expected output is all column names where the cell value in the fruit row is 'yes'

Comment: The db structure can't be changed because we are already doing queries like SELECT 'property' WHERE 'Banana' = 'yes'. I need it to work the other way around too.

Comment: You should rethink and restructure your table, perhaps a "fruit" table and a "liquid" table instead. Or a single table with coiumns that holds the item, "property" and "yes/no".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CONCAT_WS()` to concatenate all the column names where the value is `yes`. `NULL` doesn't get included by `CONCAT_WS()`, so returning that for the `no` columns will leave them out of the result.

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', IF(Banana = 'yes', 'Banana', NULL),
                      IF(Apple = 'yes', 'Apple', NULL),
                      IF(Pear = 'yes', 'Pear', NULL),
                      ...) AS fruits
FROM yourTable
WHERE property = 'fruit';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Barmar! I am going to bed now and I will get back to you tomorrow!

Comment: Well.. looks like I forgot to actually get back to you. This solution did do the trick for me at the time. In the mean time I have learned to create databases with a relational structure instead of the mess I had before. Once again, Thanks Barmar.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already have other queries that depend on this table structure, but I would still seriously consider changing the structure anyway, even if it meant rewriting some queries.

I assume the query Barmar wrote will work to get you what you want. It looks like it should, and from what I've seen, nothing is impossible for Barmar with SQL. But consider the effect this structure will have on the rest of your application.

What if you want to add an item? (Like another fruit or something.) Normally adding an item to a database would be done with an `INSERT` query. In this case you would have to use `ALTER TABLE` instead, and add a column. After you have done that, you would also have to alter the query that selects items that have a certain property (the one you're asking about here) to include the new column. You'd have to either change your application code any time you added an item, or come up with some way to dynamically include every column in the query.

What if you want to select items that have multiple properties? Obviously there aren't many liquid fruits, (unless you leave them in the fridge too long) but I assume those two aren't the only properties you're going to have. The CONCAT approaches will have trouble dealing with that. I'm sure there are ways to work around it, but you really are just working around a problem instead of fixing it.

Those are a couple of examples, but there are numerous other issues that will make this structure a real pain to deal with.

A less cumbersome way to deal with a many-to-many relationship like this is to use three tables. One for items, one for properties, and another to link items to their properties. Like this:

```
items                 properties          item_properties

id   item_name        id   name           item_id  property_id
1    banana           1    fruit          1        1
2    apple            2    liquid         2        1
3    pear                                 3        1
4    beef                                 5        2
5    water
```

Then you can select all the properties of an item:

```
SELECT p.name
FROM properties p
INNER JOIN item_properties ip ON p.id = ip.property_id
INNER JOIN items i on ip.item_id = i.id
WHERE i.name = 'banana'
```

Or all the items with a certain property:

```
SELECT i.name
FROM items i
INNER JOIN item_properties ip ON i.id = ip.item_id
INNER JOIN properties p ON ip.property_id = p.id
WHERE p.name = 'fruit'
```

I understand if you don't want to change your existing application at this point. But for anyone who comes across this in the future, I'd really recommend a structure more like this to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you try to change the requirement to return 'banana, apple, pear'.  if you can do that, then you can hard code if statements into your query in the following pattern:

```
select concat(
         if (`banana`='yes',  'banana,', ''), 
         if (`apple` ='yes',  'apple,',  ''), 
         if (`pear`  ='yes',  'pear,',   ''), 
         if (`beef`  ='yes',  'beef,',   ''), 
         if (`water` ='yes',  'water,',  '')
   ) as properties 
from table1
where ...
```

Comment: You too thanks for your reply Xeo! I am going to bed now and I will get back to you tomorrow!